# The list of symbols has the bibliography heading

Tags: sectioning, header-footer

I have a section in my thesis which includes some mathematical notations.
This section is after Bibligraphy. My problem is that the second page of this list
appears with bibliography heading.  How can i solve this problem?
This is my main file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amscd, amsfonts, amssymb,graphicx, grffile, color, mathrsfs}
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
%\usepackage[plainpages=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{xtocinc}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\def\dis{\displaystyle}
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
\textwidth = 15.8 cm \textheight = 22.3 CM \oddsidemargin = 0.7 cm
\evensidemargin = 2.1 cm
\topmargin = -0.5 cm
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{defn}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\theoremstyle{remark} \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{roman}
 \typeout{Declaration}
\include{declaration}
\include{abstract}
\input{introduction}
\baselineskip=0.9 cm
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1} \pagestyle{headings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents
\input{ch1}
\input{ch2}
\input{ch3}
\input{ch4}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{XBib}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notation}
\input{sym}
\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Subject index}
\input{ind2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you reduce your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), which will make it much easier for others to help?

Answer (score 1):

unless the `sym` file starts with a `\chapter` command you will probably have to add `\markboth{Notation}{Notation} just after the relevant`\addcontentsline`.

if `sym` *does* contain a `\chapter` command, you should add the `\markboth` after that line.

however, a `\chapter` command *should* create proper running heads, so i assume you have
headed the notation list by some other method.